# Intrigued at the idea of putting a general in charge,...?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

> Intrigued at the idea of putting a general in charge, Mr. Trump offered the job to Mr. Kelly a few days ago.

Is the first part of the sentence before the comma called a dangling modifier, and is it describing how Trump is feeling about the idea...?

Is intrigued followed by "by something" or "at something"?

Comment: It's not a ***dangling*** modifier, because that's when the subject of the verb in the "fronted" modifier (***intrigued***, here) doesn't follow immediately after that modifier. In your example, the subject *(**Mr Tramp**)* does appear in the expected position, so the modifier ***isn't*** left "dangling" (unresolved). You're quite right that ***intrigued*** is normally followed by ***by** [the thing which intrigues]*, but that's a matter of idiomatically established preference, not a "rule" of grammar.

Comment: Note that it's not so much *describing how Tramp is feeling about the idea* - rather, it's ***explaining why** Tramp offered the job to Kelly*.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. So could we call this an absolute phrase? Because it "intrigued" describes the sentence as a whole, and not a specific noun as you mentioned. @FumbleFingers

Comment: I'm not much interested in "grammar terminology" at that level (I had no idea what an [absolute phrase](http://www.testmagic.com/grammar/explanations/phrases/absolute-phrases-introduction.asp) was until I just looked it up). But according to that link, *absolute phrases themselves do NOT contain verbs*, so I guess the answer is *NO - your example isn't one of those*.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it describes "the sentence as a whole" but Trump's state of mind. Here's an example of an absolute:  *The last train for the day having departed, they decided to take the bus.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is a lengthy phrase,

> Intrigued at the idea of putting a general in charge...

is not a [dangling modifier](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/597/1/), as it does immediately precede Mr. Trump, the noun it is modifying, as @FumbleFingers indicated in his comment. A dangling modifier is present in this variant of the sentence:

> Intrigued at the idea of putting a general in charge, the job was offered by Mr. Trump to Mr. Kelly a few days ago.

or even worse,

> Intrigued at the idea of putting a general in charge, Mr. Kelly was offered the job by Mr. Trump a few days ago.

So what is it? I would classify it as a [participial phrase](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/02/), where the entire phrase is an adjective modifying Mr. Trump. Specifically, it modifies his state of mind, or intent, for offering the job to Mr. Kelly, as pointed out by @Tᴚoɯɐuo.

Finally, "intrigued at" appears to be the [least common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intrigued%20with%2C%20intrigued%20by%2C%20intrigued%20at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintrigued%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintrigued%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintrigued%20at%3B%2Cc0) use among "intrigued by," "intrigued with," and "intrigued at." However, all three could be considered valid uses.

Comment: the link that you put in the words "dangling modifier" is not working.

Comment: @StevanSlewa Thank you for pointing that out. I've corrected the link.